# How can export data from html table to excel?

Tags: php, excel

I have a table in html file and want to export it to an excel file automatically without ask me for save or open it.
My code is(in PHP) :

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=airport.xls");

echo "<html>";
echo "<body>";
echo "$list";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Try a plugin https://github.com/elidickinson/php-export-data

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to export html table to excel or pdf in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541000/how-to-export-html-table-to-excel-or-pdf-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

I think your php code is perfect for excell download ,but your need is not related to code that disable popup block of "save or open " for that you may refer some other site like

[Disable “Do you want to open or save this file?” download prompt"](http://9to5it.com/internet-explorer-disable-do-you-want-to-open-or-save-this-file-prompt/)